# PHP: how to get result when $result has fields but no rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a simple program in PHP where you enter a Genus name and a Species name into a form and the program outputs the ID in the database (along with the genus and species name) associated with that Genus/Species record.

The $result of my query has no rows, (but is correctly showing that it has 3 fields) so I'm wondering how to extract that data.

My code is below (it doesn't work. and I'm not getting any error messages)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<?php //taxa-form.php
require_once 'login.php';

$connection=
    new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
if ($connection->connect_error) {die($connection->connect_error);}

 ?>
 <form action="status-form.php" method="post"><pre>

   Genus <input type="text" name='Genus' >
  Species <input type="text" name='Species'>


  <input type="submit" value="GET ID">
  </pre></form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Genus']) &&
     isset($_POST['Species']))
 {
 $Genus=get_post($connection, 'Genus');
 $Species=get_post($connection,'Species');



  $query="SELECT Taxa_ID, Genus, Species FROM taxa WHERE Genus =
           'Genus' AND Species ='Species'";  

 $result= $connection->query($query);

 if(!$result) {echo "no result: $query<br> .$connection->error. <br>";}
 // THIS CODE RETURNS 0 ROWS BUT IT RETURNS 3 FIELDS

 $fields= $result->field_count; 


 for ($j=0; $j<$fields; ++$j)
 {
     $result->data_seek($j);
     $result_array=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

     echo $result_array[$j];
 }


 }
 function get_post($connection, $var)
    {
    return $connection->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
    }    
 ?>
```

Comment: this code can't work just looking at your error for result ?

Comment: Hey You need to learn how to fetch data , Here

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp

Comment: nothing seems to be working for me. I've tried fetch_object, fetch_assoc, and fetch_row. I don't know if the problem is that my $result has zero rows and these functions grab data from rows??